Would this way of expanding the Laurent series for $f(z)= \dfrac{e^z}{1-z}$ be correct?
Let $f(z)= \dfrac{e^z}{1-z}$, then the Laurent series of $f$ around $z=0$ is $$\frac{1}{1-z} e^z = \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n\right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)=(1+z+z^2+\cdots )(1+ z+ \frac{z^2}{2!}+ \frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots)$$ when $0<|z|<1$.
Is this expansion correct? If not, how can I go about expanding it?

You haven't expanded it!

You have only written a product of series. A Laurent series is a single series.

You still need to apply Cauchy's product formula in order to expand the product. By the way, are you sure you are interested in the expansion around $z = 1$ instead of $z = 0$, because the latter will produce a mere analytic Taylor series ?

Your series is
$$\sum_{i\geq0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\dfrac{z^{i+j}}{i!}$$
Tip/hint: $i+j=k$
